# How many bags can I check in as part of the included luggage allowance on Thomson Airways?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, thomson-airways

I have a flight booked with Thomson Airways, but I am quite unsure regarding the hold luggage allowance. I have already checked [The Baggage allowance page](http://www.thomson.co.uk/destinations/info/faq/baggage-allowance), but they don't say anything about maximum weight or number of bags.

I am flying alone in the flight only mode and my boarding card says that I can have **25kg** of hold luggage which can be upgraded to 30kg. The boarding card doesn't say anything about the number of suitcases, but It says that the maximum weight per luggage piece is 23Kg.

I am looking for someone with experience flying with Thomson who can tell me **how many pieces of hold luggage I can have**.

It doesn't make sense that my allowance is 25Kg if the maximum per suitcase is 23Kg and the number of pieces of luggage is one. 
I can't combine weight with anybody else because I and flying alone.

Comment: The way it's worded implies total weight.

Comment: 25kg is an unusual allowance. Above 23kg usually requires that a heavy bag label is applied, so that normally demarcates luggage limits, with 32kg being the upper limit allowed following payment or status. 25kg also isn't listed on the linked page

Comment: Your allowance seems to vary with the type of holiday you've booked with them, which did you book ? Package holiday, flight only, ski holiday ?

Comment: @blackbird the link also says that the allowed baggage will be printed on the ticket; OP says that it's 25Kg, but is that a typo and meant to be 23? As to the second question re: number of bags, Thomson says that groups can combine weight allowance, so two bags, yes, with combined weight not to exceed 23kg, right?

Comment: Thomson don't seem to make clear what their baggage allowances are. However, we have no more information than you do, and our guesses at what their policy means are just guesses. You should contact Thomson and ask them for clarification.

Comment: I am going to update my question, but what I want to know is basically how many bags I can have.

Comment: @JCalcines, I am sure this is about hold luggage but can you include that in the question? Some people seem to miss that bit.